# Why the event handler is executed more than once with JQuery on() API?

Tags: jquery, events

When I am using on() to listen to event, I find the event handler is called more than once. Code as below:

html:

```
<div id="container">
<div>
    <div><input type="text"/></div>        
</div>    
</div>
```

JS:

```
var $div = $('#container'), $input = $('input');

$div.on('validate', 'div', function() {
    console.log('div');
});

$input.blur(function() {
    $(this).trigger('validate');
});
```

[Here is the updated DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ianjiang/egcVb/3/)

- Then the 'validate' handler is called twice.
- When I dig into JQuery
  source code, I find that JQuery will find the parent node of event
  target and check the seletor matched or not.
- If matched the selector,
  the handler queue will be pushed one more the handleobj. In the
  example, between event target and listener element div#contianer,
  there are two hierarchical divs.
- In result, the handler queue has two
  event handler which are the same event handler function instance.

My question is: How to use selector correctly to prevent event handler be called more than once? Thanks.

I think to answer this question, we should carefully read the related source code in JQuery:

```
// Determine handlers that should run if there are delegated events
        // Avoid non-left-click bubbling in Firefox (#3861)
        if ( delegateCount && !(event.button && event.type === "click") ) {

            // Pregenerate a single jQuery object for reuse with .is()
            jqcur = jQuery(this);
            jqcur.context = this.ownerDocument || this;

            for ( cur = event.target; cur != this; cur = cur.parentNode || this ) {

                // Don't process events on disabled elements (#6911, #8165)
                if ( cur.disabled !== true ) {
                    selMatch = {};
                    matches = [];
                    jqcur[0] = cur;
                    for ( i = 0; i < delegateCount; i++ ) {
                        handleObj = handlers[ i ];
                        sel = handleObj.selector;

                        if ( selMatch[ sel ] === undefined ) {
                            selMatch[ sel ] = (
                                handleObj.quick ? quickIs( cur, handleObj.quick ) : jqcur.is( sel )
                            );
                        }
                        if ( selMatch[ sel ] ) {
                            matches.push( handleObj );
                        }
                    }
                    if ( matches.length ) {
                        handlerQueue.push({ elem: cur, matches: matches });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Add code example link: http://jsfiddle.net/ianjiang/egcVb/

Comment: I presume what you're seeing is event delegation/propagation.  Some events propagate up the DOM hierarchy to parents.  You can stop propagation with `event.stopPropagation()`.

Comment: I don't know why, but if you do a `return false;` after the `console.log` statement it only logs once.

Comment: [Demonstration of the problem.](http://jsfiddle.net/egcVb/2/)

Comment: Yes, I realize JQuery custom event by trigger can be bubble up. But this is by design? Once the selector is matched, the handler queue will be added one more same handler.

Comment: Your code essentially means 'call the event handler for every div within the container when a `validate` event is fired within the container'. Thats exactly what the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handlereventObject) say. No need to dig into the source code.

Answer (score 0):

> $input.blur(function() {$(this).trigger('validate');});' Only input triggers 
>   validate event. So I don't think means "work for onblur for every elements on DOM

This is wrong because trigger bubble up the DOM tree, and triggers the same event for parent elements.

[From DOCS](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

> As of jQuery 1.3, .trigger()ed events bubble up the DOM tree; an event handler can stop  the bubbling by returning false from the handler or calling the .stopPropagation() method on the event object passed into the event

So there are two divs inside the `div#container`,

```
$input.blur(function() {$(this).trigger('validate');});
```

also triggers for those two divs.

Here is an example that you can see which element is `currentTarget`,

http://jsfiddle.net/egcVb/4/

```
$div.on('validate', 'div', function(e) {
    console.log(e.currentTarget);
});
```

If you want to stop bubbling, just return false from that event.

http://jsfiddle.net/egcVb/5/

```
$div.on('validate', 'div', function(e) {
    console.log(e.currentTarget);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: '$input.blur(function() {$(this).trigger('validate');});' Only input triggers validate event. So I don't think means "work for onblur for every elements on DOM

Comment: And actually there are two div elements and one input element in div#container.

Comment: The code in your jsFiddle example and the code you wrote down here are different. Which one do you reference?

Comment: The later one. Sorry about that.

Comment: could you point the key words in document which prove "triggers the same event for parent elements." Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This means: bind 'validate' event on $div, but include it for each div descendant too.

```
$div.on('validate', 'div', function() {
    console.log('div');
});
```

See [jQuery `on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), parameter `selector`:

> A selector string to filter the descendants of the selected elements
>   that trigger the event. If the selector is null or omitted, the event
>   is always triggered when it reaches the selected element.

Use this:

```
$div.on('validate', function() {
    console.log('div');
});
```

...and you will se just one event handled.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't mention the handler queue will be added one more same handler function instance. Does it by design?

Comment: I don't understand `the handler queue will be added one more same handler function instance`, but jQuery will by design pass through all filtered children and logically attach event handlers to them. As a result you will get 2 events handled. Try to differentiate those two inner div's by some class name and include that in `on` selector and you will see.

Comment: `handlerQueue.push({ elem: cur, matches: matches });` You can see the related source code for dispatch function in JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a good reason to bind the event handler to the *div* instead of the *input*, you can change your event handler to look like this:

```
$div.on('validate', '*', function(event) {
    var isRelevant = false;
    $(this).children().each(function(){
        if (this === event.target){
            isRelevant = true;
        }
    });

    if (isRelevant){
        console.log('div');
    }
});
```

This snippet checks if the **event.target** from which the event emanates ([doc](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/)), is one of the direct children of the element the event has propagated to.
*isRelevant* will only be *true* for the inner div.

You can check it out also in a fork I made off your example: http://jsfiddle.net/BwseN/